# How do I solve a 403 or redirect error in IIS Manager

Tags: redirect, iis, http-status-code-403, http-redirect, iis-10

403 or redirect error keeps appearing in the browser even though I have done my redirects properly in IIS Manager. I have tried clearing my cookies, this did not work.

Edit: enabled direct browsing in IIS Manager and this is the result (the fifth image)

[redirect checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1nxQ.png)

[result of redirect checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmeXR.png)

[redirect not checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy4G2.png)

[result of redirect not checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fsxE.png)

[result of enabling direct browsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38VLO.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the redirect function in the URL Rewrite module:

[image]

```
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="off" />
              </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

If you haven’t installed URL Rewrite yet, you can download URL Rewrite from this [link](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).